Errors when trying to install Synology ActiveBackupBusinessAgent
The installation script resulted in:
....
 * start installing snapshot driver and agent service
 * snapshot driver has not installed, installing snapshot driver
 * installing synosnap-0.10.19.deb
(Reading database ... 285125 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack synosnap-0.10.19.deb ...
rmmod: ERROR: Module synosnap is not currently loaded
Deleting module synosnap-0.10.19 completely from the DKMS tree.
Unpacking synosnap (0.10.19) over (0.10.19) ...
Setting up synosnap (0.10.19) ...
Loading new synosnap-0.10.19 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-28-generic 6.5.0-35-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-28-generic
xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/synosnap.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package synosnap (--install):
 installed synosnap package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 synosnap
 * failed to install snapshot driver


Looking in make.log as advised resulted in:
root@soren-ws:/var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build# cat make.log
DKMS make.log for synosnap-0.10.19 for kernel 6.5.0-28-generic (x86_64)
sön 19 maj 2024 12:52:39 CEST
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/dattobd.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/dattobd.c:8:
/var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/includes.h:13:10: fatal error: linux/genhd.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #include <linux/genhd.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/dattobd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic/Makefile:2039: /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-28-generic'

Conclusion: Seems to be a faulty identification of gcc versions. Both used is 12.3.0 ????
Did some more investigation:
Investigated further and got an answer from ChatGPT on this question:
is there a difference between x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
and  gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0 ?
Asnswer: The x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 and gcc-12 versions you mentioned refer to the same GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) version, specifically version 12.3.0, but they may have different configurations or purposes.
Here are the primary differences:

Naming and Target Triplet:

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 explicitly includes the target triplet x86_64-linux-gnu, indicating that it is configured to target the x86_64 architecture on a GNU/Linux system.
gcc-12 is a more general name and might be a symlink or an alias to a specific target compiler. It is typically the default GCC version installed and used for compiling code on your system.


Configuration and Usage:

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 is likely a version of GCC configured specifically for cross-compiling or targeting the x86_64-linux-gnu architecture. It might include specific configurations and libraries for that target environment.
gcc-12 is the default GCC compiler that may be configured to target the native architecture of the host system, which in most cases will be x86_64-linux-gnu on a typical Ubuntu system.


Installation Paths:

Both compilers are likely installed through the Ubuntu package manager, but they might be located in different directories or have different symlinks pointing to them.
You can check the installation paths and configurations using the which and gcc --version commands to see if they refer to the same binary or different ones.


Environment and Usage Scenarios:

Developers often use x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 in scenarios where explicit control over the target architecture is needed, such as in cross-compilation.
The gcc-12 command is commonly used for general-purpose compilation tasks on the native system architecture.



Checking Differences
To check if they are the same or different on your system, you can use the following commands:

Check the paths:
which x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
which gcc-12


Check the versions:
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 --version
gcc-12 --version


Compare the binaries:
ls -l $(which x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12)
ls -l $(which gcc-12)



By comparing the output of these commands, you can determine if x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 and gcc-12 are the same binary or if they are different binaries with potentially different configurations.
Checking both:
soren@soren-ws:~$ ls -l $(which x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1387752 maj 13  2023 /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
soren@soren-ws:~$ ls -l $(which gcc-12)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 maj 13  2023 /usr/bin/gcc-12 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12
Conclusion: what is the difference?
